# XML reader attribute with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, attributes, xmlreader

I want to read an xml file. And to all its attribute I need.

High Time tag is repeated 36 times

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<weatherdata>
  <!-- ... -->
  <forecast>
    <tabular>
      <time from="2016-09-28T15:30:00" to="2016-09-28T18:30:00" period="2">
        <!-- Valid from 2016-09-28T15:30:00 to 2016-09-28T18:30:00 -->
        <symbol number="1" numberEx="1" name="Clear sky" var="01d" />
        <precipitation value="0" />
        <!-- Valid at 2016-09-28T15:30:00 -->
        <windDirection deg="225.9" code="SW" name="Southwest" />
        <windSpeed mps="7.5" name="Moderate breeze" />
        <temperature unit="celsius" value="24" />
        <pressure unit="hPa" value="1007.5" />
      </time>
      <time from="2016-09-28T18:30:00" to="2016-09-29T00:30:00" period="3">
        <!-- Valid from 2016-09-28T18:30:00 to 2016-09-29T00:30:00 -->
        <symbol number="3" numberEx="3" name="Partly cloudy" var="mf/03n.89" />
        <precipitation value="0" />
        <!-- Valid at 2016-09-28T18:30:00 -->
        <windDirection deg="219.1" code="SW" name="Southwest" />
        <windSpeed mps="4.6" name="Gentle breeze" />
        <temperature unit="celsius" value="19" />
        <pressure unit="hPa" value="1008.5" />
      </time>
```

etc.

Comment: What programming language? Add the corresponding tag, please. Also, paste the XML snippet here with the code foramtting, not as a picture with the placeholder link text.

Comment: asp.net and URL= http://www.yr.no/place/Iran/East_Azarbaijan/Bostānābād/forecast.xml

Comment: help me please. no